DLT Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()
I'm performing a readStream in my DLT pipeline:
sourced = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles").option("cloudFiles.format", "csv").schema(schema).load(file_path, header=True, inferSchema=True, sep="|")

There are two columns in this data, let's say A and B.  I need to check if there are any rows where the values between these two columns are different, if so then reject the file.  I was originally going to do this with the built-in @dlt.expect_all_or_fail, but I'm unable to do so because I don't want these two columns to be in the end output as I will be dropping them.
So my approach was to get a count of how many records where they are different, and then throw an error if it's bigger than 0:
if sourced.filter(col("A") != col("B")).count() > 0:
  raise ValueError(f"ERROR!!!")

Unfortunately I get this error instead:
Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()

I know if I change from readStream to read, then it all works fine, but I need streaming unfortunately, what's the best way round this?

You can create a temporary table on the autoloader step and have your expectations validated. The next step you can read the temp table and drop the columns that you do not need to create your final table.
This way, if at anytime your expectations fail, your pipeline will fail. But if they pass, the columns will dropped before loading to the final output table.
Something like
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import json
from datetime import datetime
import dlt

@dlt.table(name=f"TEMP_CUST_AUTO",temporary=True)
#@dlt.expect_all_or_fail({"valid columns" , "col(“A”) = col(“B”)"})
@dlt.expect_all_or_fail({"valid_columns": "A = B"})
def incremental_view():
    return(spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles") \
        .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", f"abfss://schema@jridatalakesng.dfs.core.windows.net/SO_CUST_AUTO/") \
        .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv") \
        .option("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes", "true") \
        .option("cloudFiles.includeExistingFiles","true") \
        .load("abfss://raw@jridatalakesng.dfs.core.windows.net/cust/"))

@dlt.table(name=f"BRONZE_CUST_AUTO")
def incremental_bronze():
    df  = spark.sql("SELECT customer_id,name,mobile_number  FROM STREAM LIVE.TEMP_CUST_AUTO")
    return(df)

The python reference for expectations can be found here. And the  python reference for DLT can be found here.
